# What are the minimum and maximum versions of Webpack (including minor versions) that angular 12, 13, 14 and 15 releases supports?

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, webpack-5, angular-webpack

I want to upgrade the webpack component in my project.

I am currently running angular 12 version in my web application.

So I wanted to upgraded the latest compatible version of Webpack that in line compatable with angular 12 release?

Wanted to know in-line compatable version of webpack (including minor release version) with angular 12

Comment: Angular controls the version of webpack. Why do you care about it? It shouldn't even be a dependency in your project if you are using the Angular CLI. Also there are versions of Angular which support both Webpack 4 and Webpack 5.